# How to add subviews in Table View Cell while Expanding them and perform actions on their elements of SubViews?

Tags: ios, swift3, tableview, subview, uitableview

[image: .]

Image Depicting that I have to add this kind of subview to my existing cell and also same subview on multiple clicks of Add icon.

I am facing difficulties in adding subview. If anyone can provide me the correct approach to handle out this structure, help me out.

Answer (score 2):

You can design your cell for a expanded mode in interface builder and set the auto layout constraint correctly instead of adding subview to the tableView cell while cell is expanding.

1) In interface builder design your cell's view for expanded cell and add subviews  in a view which you want to be added while cell is expanded.

2) Now set the auto layout constraint correctly and don't forget to set the height constraint for the view which contains all the subviews for your expended cell.

3) Take the outlet of the height constraint, you created in step 2.

4) Now set the height constraint's constant value to 0 for the normal cell and a value `> 0` for the expanded cell.

```
    heightConstraint.constant = 100
```

Comment: Actually If i click Add icon second time it will add that view second time and so on... I have seen tutorials which shows Expanding to a single view and collapsing it.I am in confusion how could I create such cells by autolayout which handles multiple add button clicks.

Comment: you have to check it while you click on a  add icon button, if  it is already expended then you have to collapse it by setting the value 0 for the heightConstaint

Comment: if heightConstraint.constant == 0{ // expand the cell}else{//collapse the cell}

Comment: I am thinking I can't use the Height Constraint. Once I expand cell , then I have to perform some action on "From Button Click" & "To Button Click". So If I create all the things in a single cell. I may not be able to identify index path.row for that particular button if all buttons are in single Cell. If i am not able to specify you exactly, let me know.

Comment: Your cell will be same, it's not changing as you expand it or collapse it.To identify the index path for the button, you can assign the value to the tag property of the button while you create the cell in the datasource method of the tableview cellForRowAtIndexpath as: yourButton.tag = indexPath.row

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to treat each addition as a new row and keep track of that, rather than put it all in one cell.

Another way to do this is to add another tableview inside this cell and increase its height based on the number of rows it has. But I am not sure about performance in that case.